# How to remove localization from file

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm trying to unlocalize xib and storyboard files, and keep all strings in Localizable.strings. How do I do this in XCode?

I've tried to uncheck all languages in the File Inspector, but if I remove the last language the whole file disappears.

[image]

A file that is not localized looks like this:

[image]

Unlocalized files wont appear when you add a new language or when you export localizations with xliff.

Comment: Which Xcode you are using?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is a pretty stupid way, but the only one I found out working if you want to restore the default:

1. Move the xib or Storyboard files from the `Base.lproj`folder to your main project folder back (within the Finder).
2. Delete the reference of the XIB/Storyboard files (in XCode)
3. Reimport all of them back to your XCode project and you are done

Comment: Is this still the only way?

Comment: @anoop4real hasnt changed that much, so I think yes.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode create a `Localizable.strings` file.
In Xcode select the file and on the right panel, checkbox the languages you want for it.
Then copy/pasta the files/strings into the place you want them.
Then remove the old languages for the xib/storyboard.

[image]